# Can I programmatically tell which application will open a given URL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, url-scheme, uiapplication

I'm trying to figure out which iOS application a given URL will be opened in.

I know that "http://..." URLs will open in Safari and that "twitter://..." URLs, for example, will open in the Twitter app, but is there a way to get that information programmatically?

I'm looking for a method that I can call with a URL (or just the scheme/protocol) to find out the bundle ID (or even just the localized name) of the app that will be invoked when `-openURL` is called.

Does something like the following exist?

```
[UIApplication handlerForURL:someUrl]; // @"com.dev.app"
```

Comment: Nope. There's also no way to open a URL with a specific app (to avoid another one "hijacking" a URL scheme, for example).

Comment: In addition, the docs specifically mention that if two apps have the same URL scheme, it is undefined which one will be opened.

Answer (score 2):

On the Mac, there's an API function called [`LSGetApplicationForURL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/LSGetApplicationForURL) in the Launch Services framework that does this for you.

While it's likely that the same API function exists in iOS, [Launch Services is private API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html).

So no, you can't do this on iOS.

There is [a boolean method on `UIApplication` that will tell *if* a URL can be opened](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL%3a), but that's not the same thing as knowing *how* it will be opened.